# inequality for ratio of Gamma functions

Tags: functions, inequality, factorial, gamma-function

Let $N,q$ be natural  numbers.
Find the best upper and lower bound (non-asymptotic) for
$$
\frac{\Gamma(2q)}{\Gamma(q)}\frac{\Gamma(q+N/2)}{\Gamma(2(q+N/2))}=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^q(2q-(2k+1))}{\prod_{\ell=1}^{q+N/2}(2(q+N/2)-(2\ell+1))}
$$